# Angular2: passing ALL the attributes to the child component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

Don't even know the proper terminology to explain this *problem*

so, imagine this scenario...

There is a form-input-component and capturing some attributes and passing it down to the markup inside

```
<form-input placeholder="Enter your name" label="First name" [(ngModel)]="name" ngDefaultControl></form-input>
```

So, this is the markup, hope is pretty self explanatory...

obviously in the ts I have

```
  @Input() label: string = '';
  @Input() placeholder: string = '';
```

and then in the view I have something down these lines

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{label}}
    <input type="text" [placeholder]="placeholder" [(ngModel)] = "ngModel">
</div>
```

Now, all works fine so far...

but let's say I want to add the validation rules around it...
or add other attributes that I don't capture via `@Input()`

How can I pass down anything else that comes down from `<form-input>` to my `<input>` in the view?

Comment: Pass one object instead?

Comment: `<form-input form-data="{placeholder:'Enter your name here', label:'First Name'}"`

Comment: nah, don't want that... would like to have exact same syntax, so if I add maxlength to the form-input (or any other valid attribute), it would show on input inside as well, without specifying @Input() in the ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the lazy ones:

```
export class FormInput implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(NgModel, {read: ElementRef}) inpElementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    const attributes = this.elementRef.nativeElement.attributes;
    const inpAttributes = this.inpElementRef.nativeElement.attributes;
    for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; ++i) {
      let attribute = attributes.item(i);
      if (attribute.name === 'ngModel' ||
        inpAttributes.getNamedItemNS(attribute.namespaceURI, attribute.name)
      ) {
        continue;
      }
      this.inpElementRef.nativeElement.setAttributeNS(attribute.namespaceURI, attribute.name, attribute.value);
    }
  }
}
```

`ngAfterViewInit` won't work if you nest multiple components which pass attributes, because `ngAfterViewInit` will be called for inner elements before outer elements. I.e. the inner component will pass its attributes before it received attributes from the outer component, so the inner most element won't receive the attributes from the outer most element. That's why I'm using `ngOnInit` here.

Comment: Where'd ya get this.elementRef from

Comment: @RNMR You can inject it. It seems I forgot to paste the respective code. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate on the DOM attributes of your component :

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...

export class FormInput {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    // Iterate here over el.nativeElement.attributes
    // and add them to you child element (input)
  }
}
```

Comment: well, I do that and use ViewChild to identify the input element... and the use setAttribute to map the ones allowed... the attribute is set, but angular is not reacting to that (let's say minlength)... is not valdiating against it... but if I do it directly... it works good... do I need to call some angular stuff to re-initialize the input element as angular's form element after assign all the attributes?

Comment: @DS_web_developer I know I'm a bit late to this party but the logic in this example happens in the constructor, which fires before the dom is built. I'd put your logic somewhere on or after ngOnInit (perhaps even in ngAfterViewInit). That might make a difference.