# Angular perfect fowarding of component properties to a child component

Tags: angular

I recently became aware of the following technique in React to foward properties to child components. This uses destructuring assignment:

```
const MyInputComponent = (props) => <input {...props} />
```

Using this you can perfectly wrap components without re-implementing their interface.

Is there a similar technique for Angular components?

Edit: found duplicate [Angular2: passing ALL the attributes to the child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785547/angular2-passing-all-the-attributes-to-the-child-component)

Comment: How do you want to use this component?

Comment: are you trying to find out the way to communicate between two parent and child component ?

Comment: I don't see here anything new or different. it works the same in angular. btw, passing params without interface can be done but then you miss the point of typescript.

Comment: @RahulSingh I want to wrap an <input> to add some html elements around it for styling and animation. Else I would have to repeat these elements many times. But I want to avoid dealing with events and other input properties like "id" or "step" or "disabled" or "max" or "min" etc.

Comment: @Avi can you show an example?

Comment: @ErikvanVelzen isnt it same as event emitters ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to wrap an  to add some html elements around it for
>   styling and animation. Else I would have to repeat these elements many
>   times.

ngcontent is your friend!

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'my-wrapper',
      template: `
        <h1>my fancy header</h1>
        <ng-content>YOUR INPUT WILL GO HERE</ng-content>

        `
    })
```

markup anywhere you want to use the wrapper:

```
    <div>
       <my-wrapper>
          <input .../>
       </my-wrapper>
   </div>
```

as you can see, the wrapper can have any template you want with any params you like.
the inner html you put inside can have any markup you want with any params you like.

Comment: Your are correct that that meets the requirements that I described for you though obviously this is a less powerfull approach because I won't be able to intercept the properties to the children or add my own.