# How to pass all attributes from Angular component to template

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a custom Angular 4 component where I use `<img>` as template. The component is selector is `i-image`, so it renders in UI like this:

```
<i-image _ngcontent-c0="" alt="this is alt" ng-reflect-path="/default-image.jpg" ng-reflect-lqip="[object Object]">
    <img src="example.com/a.jpg">
</i-image>
```

The actual code in component which uses the `i-image` is as follows:

```
<i-image path="{{path}}" [lqip]="{}" alt="this is alt"></i-image>
```

My intention is to take all attributes provided by user on `i-image` and apply them to `img` tag. For example `alt` is provided here, but it doesn't get applied to the `img` tag. I don't want to do one to one mapping for all possible attributes, rather trust user on whatever he wants to provide, and simply add those attributes to `img` tag before rendering.

Is this possible at all? If yes, can you point me in right direction. I can figure out the code, just need the idea on how to do this within Angular ways.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible without breaking Angular best practices.  I question whether this is actually desirable?  Allowing the user to inject arbitrary HTML that the browser will render is inherently unsafe.  This is how XSS attacks are created.

Comment: Perhaps you can achieve what you want by using Angular's content projection. It depends on what `i-image` is supposed to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785547/angular2-passing-all-the-attributes-to-the-child-component

Answer (score 0):

yes use content projection for that place the  tag with a selector in  and then pass that whole html code in that selector